# Is it correct to use infrastructure as a countable noun in this context?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

My understanding of the word "infrastructure" is that it is uncountable.

However, upon looking it up in Oxford Learner's Dictionary, I found that it is classified as "countable, uncountable." http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/infrastructure

With that in mind, my question is: is the following sentence grammatical? It seems wrong to me:

> I enjoy the city infrastructures and the kindness of the local people.

EDIT: This was written by a student from a developing country about her experience living in a developed one.

Comment: I'd say that one city has one infrastructure. Also, I'm not too sure I'd say 'I enjoy the roads, the power supply, the refuse collection service,  the sewerage system ...'. Certainly not coupled with 'and the kindness of the local people'. I'd use 'I really appreciate how problem-free the city's infrastructure is'.

Comment: Almost certainly the count usage refers to different cities' (etc) infrastructures: 'the rail infrastructures in Norway and Belgium' (ie 'the rail infrastructure in Norway and that in Belgium'). // We tend to address the English involved, and a question like 'Correct?: ... (rather than 'Is it correct to use the plural count form 'infrastructures' here?') may invite all sorts of comments on grammaticality and idiomaticity.

Comment: It's not correct with "the" and the plural.   I enjoy city infrastructures. I enjoy the city infrastructure.  I enjoy city infrastructure.    Not ok -> I enjoy the city infrastructures  (because in the context of a single city the infrastructure is uncountable. The city has its infrastructure.).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth How about *Our city has five basic infrastructures - power, refuse, transport, water and sewage*.

Comment: Looking at contextual translations of the French word "infrastuctures" (plural), all corresponding English sentences systematically use the  singular. Note that, in your example, "facilities" is perhaps a better choice than "infrastructure".

Comment: Interesting perspective, @Graffito. Does the word "facilities" denote a train system, for instance? It seems to me that "infrastructure" would include roads and rails, whereas "facilities" would not.

Comment: @WS2 - You would then accept [two aircrafts](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=two+aircraft%2C+two+aircrafts&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctwo%20aircraft%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwo%20aircrafts%3B%2Cc0") ?

Comment: @WS2 I might choose to rephrase that as "Our city's infrastructure includes power, refuse, transport, etc."

Comment: Roads, airports and trains are "transport facilities" (or transportation facilities).

Comment: @Graffito How do "transport facilities" differ from "transport infrastructure"?

Comment: To keep it simple, infrastructure refers to the "systems", whilst facilities refers to the "services" provided by the systems.

Comment: @Graffito So a person cannot enjoy infrastructure on an individual level, unless he or she were a city planner or the like.

Comment: @Graffito I would accept that the plural is possibly *infrastructure* (as with *aircraft*). But I still feel certain that there can be more than one of them. Isn't it logical? I mean could there be just one 'infrastructure' - for the entire world - at any one time?

Comment: The Wikipedia definition: 'Infrastructure refers to the fundamental facilities and systems serving a country, city, or area,[1] including the services and facilities necessary for its economy to function.' makes the term essentially a collective noun for sewerage, water supply, roads/public transport ..., making 'Our city has five basic infrastructures' very odd if not unacceptable. Doubtless countification into the individual domain meanings (the electricity infrastructure) (parallelling that into different locations) is under way, but the collective usage is idiomatic here.  (OP's example).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But if *infrastructure* is a thing (unlike happiness or excitement), it must be possible for there to exist at any one time more than one of them e.g. *If one compares the social infrastructure(s) of Birmingham, Manchester, and Leeds one finds they operate in entirely different ways.*

Comment: @WS2 Your 'but' is inappropriate. I've already mentioned this. Twice. Once in the previous comment. 'Almost certainly the count usage refers to different cities' (etc) infrastructures' /   / 'Doubtless countification into the individual domain meanings (the electricity infrastructure) (**parallelling that into different locations** [eg Birmingham, Manchester, and Leeds]) is under way.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I had not noticed that you had clearly agreed that *infrastructure* was a count noun with a plural. But I can now see  reading between the lines that you have. Of course cities aren't the only things which have infrastructures - political parties, the Roman Catholic Church, the Premier League, the criminal underworld - each has an *infrastructure*.

Comment: @WS2 Hence the 'etc'.

Answer (score 2):

A cursory Google search suggests that the majority of attestations of the plural **infrastructures** will be found in books and articles authored by non-native speakers. (I know, I know, a name is not conclusive evidence of anything).

In the American press, we tend to see and hear the singular **infrastructure** used as a non-countable noun that encompasses sewage, water treatment, roads, electrical grid, communications, etc. Unmodified, it refers to any or all of them. We tend not to use the plural to refer to several of them together:

**The earthquake severely damaged the city's water-treatment and electrical infrastructure.**

We might even see [a plural verb after the non-count noun](https://books.google.com/books?id=fAg8YJ7uXa4C&pg=PA137&dq=%22road%20infrastructure%20were%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAWoVChMI_riKsveZyQIVhjwmCh25ZQR2#v=onepage&q=%22road%20infrastructure%20were%22&f=false):

> They seemed to rest content with the idea that road and rail
>   infrastructure *were* now treated on an equal footing... [emphasis mine]

(though this is not from a US publication)